# Single Time Slider for Multiple Data Frames--ArcMap Desktop 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, time, data-frame

This question has been asked before, but never really answered: **Is it possible to have a single time slider control that animates over multiple data frames?** Reason being, I have one main map and 4 inset maps with the same time-aware dataset (see image with main frame activated). I can only export the animation with **one frame** following time. I would like the end result to be sequential images.  Has ESRI evolved some way to control multiple frames, or can you suggest a method that would get the same result?

I am aware of the questions at these stackexchange links ([How to apply ArcGIS time slider on Multiple Data Frames at once?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/how-to-apply-arcgis-time-slider-on-multiple-data-frames-at-once) [3-years old and no solution] and ([ArcGis using the time slider to animate multiple data frames](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166894/arcgis-using-the-time-slider-to-animate-multiple-data-frames) [3-months old and no answer]). However, it seems there is a demand for an workaround here, so I would like to keep this question on the boards, though it means reposting the question.

[image: Inset Maps with Single Control]

Comment: Re-posting a duplicate question isn't the best way to go about this, unfortunately - Stack Exchange isn't like other QA forums. The two questions that you found should really be merged into a single one, which will hopefully be answered.